# Run a method when opening a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

here there is my problem.

Activty1 -> startActivity(Activity2) -> Activity2 -> startActivity(Activity1)->Activity1.
When I open the Activity1 from the Activity2 I would like to run a method in Activity1. So:

Activty1 -> startActivity(Activity2) -> Activity2 -> startActivity(Activity1)->Activity1 and run method();
How can I do that?

```
  public void domandaSuccessiva(View view){

   Intent intent = new Intent(CorrettoActivity.this, PrimaDomanda.class;
    startActivity(intent);
    PrimaDomanda primaDomanda = new PrimaDomanda();
    primaDomanda.mostraDomanda();





}
```

Comment: just call inside the onCreate method...

Comment: if i do Activity1.method(), the program crashes

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira the method onCreate doesn't start again...

Comment: @fradeb Then put it on `onResume` (http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png)

Comment: @m0skit0 its will be solve (y)

Comment: @m0skit0  public void domandaSuccessiva(View view){

       Intent intent = new Intent(CorrettoActivity.this, PrimaDomanda.class;
        startActivity(intent);
        PrimaDomanda primaDomanda = new PrimaDomanda();
        primaDomanda.mostraDomanda();
           
       



    }

Comment: Why are you posting that code? I cannot read that in a comment, at least edit your question to add it. Anyway nobody asked for the method :) I said call it on `onResume`, this is always executed. Check the Activity lifecycle I linked to.

Comment: @m0skit0 to create a onResume _> public void onResume(){} is it ok?

Comment: You need to **override** `onResume` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: @m0skit0 it is a problem. I can't call onPause, it doen't work

Comment: Who has talked about `onPause`? :/

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is move from activity A to B, B to A and then invoke a method from A, I think the following should work for you:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

e.g.,
in A, call startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity()

in B, call setResult(), this would take you back to A

in A, check for the request code in onActivityResult() and invoke your desired method